# Figure captions for knitr blocks that include links in pdf documents

Tags: knitr, bookdown

I have small bookdown 'book' that includes the following code:

````
A concept map is a diagram that shows 'ideas' and the relationship between those ideas. An example of a concept map is shown in Figure \@ref(fig:exampleCM).


```{r exampleCM, fig.show='hold', fig.cap='An example concept map --- Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Conceptmap.png "Concept Map from Wikipedia")', echo=FALSE}                                  

knitr::include_graphics('images/ConceptMap.png')                                                                                                            
```
````

If I render the book as HTML everything works as expected. The caption includes a hyperlink to wikimedia/wikipedia. I.e., the caption looks like this:

> Figure E.1: An example concept map — Source: Wikipedia

If I render the book as PDF, the caption in the PDF looks like this:

> Figure E.1: An example concept map -- Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Concep
>   "Concept Map from Wikipedia")

It seems that the rmarkdown doesn't get rendered for some reason. The LaTeX file that is produced is like this:

```
A concept map is a diagram that shows `ideas' and the relationship between those ideas. An example of a concept map is shown in Figure \ref{fig:exampleCM}.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=12.33in]{images/ConceptMap} \caption{An example concept map --- Source: [Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Conceptmap.png "Concept Map from Wikipedia")}\label{fig:exampleCM}
\end{figure}
```

I wonder how I might fix this.

Comment: This feels a bit like this [other problem I reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537760/citations-in-pdfs-produced-by-bookdown-are-incorrect/50865117#50865117) with captions.

Comment: You have to use text references in this case: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#text-references

Answer (score 1):

The comment above by [Yihui Xie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui-xie) did the trick.

Thanks for reminding me about text references.